# python and TCL: how to run scripts that need a console

Tags: python, tkinter, tcl

I am trying to run TCL scripts from Python.  I have a third-party TCL package included in the TCL script (which I have to use) which makes calls to  "console".  Because of this, if I just run the following:

```
z = x.tk.eval('source C:/somePath/GetStatsFirst2.tcl')
```

I get the following error:

```
pydev debugger: starting
WARNING!!! Unable to add paths from Appinfo: Could not find AppInfo registry entry
WARNING!!! Unable to add paths from Appinfo: Could not find AppInfo registry entry
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\lab\Documents\Public\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev_2.7.5.2013052819\pysrc\pydevd.py", line 1397, in <module>
    debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None)
  File "C:\Users\lab\Documents\Public\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev_2.7.5.2013052819\pysrc\pydevd.py", line 1090, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals) #execute the script
  File "C:\Users\lab\Documents\Public\workspace\Version 1\....\TC1.py", line 55, in <module>
    test()
  File "C:\Users\lab\Documents\Public\workspace\Version 1\....\TC1.py", line 42, in test
    z = x.tk.eval('source C:/Users/lab/Documents/Public/TCL/Scripts/GetStatsFirst2.tcl')
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name "console"
```

This definitely has something to do with the package I am using and the problem may be unavoidable.  Since there is no TK console that is opened (because I am using the TK inter class and `eval`), I get the feeling there is a way around this.  It looks to me like the package I am importing requires the existence of a TK console.  When run on the command line, or through `subprocess.call`, everything works, but in those cases a console is opened.  I am pretty sure the package is actually looking for a console.  Is there a way to create the  console along with the Tk object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahh, the `console` command.

The console command is only available

- on Windows
- only with wish
- and only in the master interp.

I suggest that you use tkcon instead. You just need to find the `tkcon.tcl` file, source it  before you source `GetStatsFirst2.tcl` and execute the following Tcl command:

```
interp alias {} console {} tkcon
```

This uses tkcon as console then.

**Edit**: You can execute that Tcl command with

```
x.tk.eval('interp alias {} console {} tkcon')
```

in Python.

Comment: The command you gave is a tcl command, but the question is asking about using tcl from a python / tkinter script. Your answer doesn't really help much.

Comment: @BryanOakley And what is `source` then? a python command? The op knows how to eval Tcl commands.

Comment: Hi Johannes, that seemed to do something because I am getting a different error now.  The script probably got a little further.  I think I will mark your response as the answer.

Comment: It was saying that it cannot load a dll.  That dll is specific to the TCL library that I have to load.  I am not sure what is going on. But maybe this has something to do with it:  {WARNING!!! Unable to add paths from Appinfo: Could not find AppInfo registry entry
WARNING!!! Unable to add paths from Appinfo: Could not find AppInfo registry entry}